# How to edit the indices of an argument array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arguments

I'm trying to write a quicksort function in JavaScript. My code is below:

```
function test_quicksort(){
  var arr = [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
  arr = quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr);
  Logger.log(arr);
}


function quicksort_setup(arr){
  var high = arr.size - 1;
  arr = quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, 0, high);
  return arr
}


function quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, low, high){
  if (low < high){
    var pi = partition(arr, low, high);
    quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, low, pi - 1);
    quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, pi + 1, high);
  }
  return arr;
}


function partition(arr, low, high){
    var pivot = arr[high];
    var smaller_boundary = low - 1;
    var curr_elem = low;
    for (; curr_elem <= high; curr_elem++){
      if (ar[curr_elem] < pivot){
            smaller_boundary++;
            swap(arr, curr_elem, smaller_boundary);
      }
    }
    swap(arr, high, smaller_boundary + 1);
    return smaller_boundary + 1;
}


function swap(arr, a, b){
  var temp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = temp;
  Logger.log(arr);
}
```

Assuming `Logger.log(arr)` is a function that prints out the contents of the array, it should print out the array properly sorted. However, whenever I run `test_quicksort`, the `[0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` is printed out instead. It seems to me that I am somehow unable to edit the array `arr` when it is passed as an argument. How can I work around this issue?

Comment: *"However, whenever I run test_quicksort, the [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] is printed out instead. It seems to me that I am somehow unable to edit the array arr when it is passed as an argument."* No, that's not why. There's no problem changing the contents of an array passed to you as an argument. There's just a bug of some kind in your code. Step through it in a debugger (there's one built into your browser and your IDE) statement by statement, viewing the contents of variables and watching the logic.

Comment: Um, you never mutate `arr` in any way

Comment: @JonasW.: I assumed that's what `swap` did, but since the code isn't in the question... :-|

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate the array passed to `test_quicksort`, you souldn't reassign a new array to it to avoid loosing it's reference (avoid `arr = newArr;`). Instead of reassigning, you can empty the array with `arr.prototype.splice` then push all elements of the sorted array into it:

```js
function test_quicksort(arr){
    var newArr = quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr);
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    arr.push(...newArr); 
}


function quicksort_by_percent_filled() {
  return [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
}

var arr = [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
test_quicksort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Basically you are right, however completely rewriting the array seems to be a bit unoptimal. Probably `swap` should directly do `[arr[one], arr[two]] = [arr[two], arr[one]]` however we cantknow for sure as its not part of the ops code

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. add a swap function,
2. take `quicksort_setup` instead of calling `quicksort_by_percent_filled` directly,
3. take the `length` instead of `size`,
4. skip call of `get_percent_filled()`, which is missing and the return value is never used,
5. use `arr` instead of `ar` in `for` loop.

```js
function swap(array, i, j) { // 1
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

function test_quicksort() {
    var arr = [0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    arr = quicksort_setup(arr); // 2
    console.log(arr);
}

function quicksort_setup(arr) {
    var high = arr.length - 1; // 3
    var percent_filled; // = get_percent_filled(); // 4
    arr = quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, 0, high, percent_filled);
    return arr
}

function quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, low, high, percent_filled) {
    if (low < high) {
        var pi = partition(arr, low, high, percent_filled);
        quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, low, pi - 1, percent_filled);
        quicksort_by_percent_filled(arr, pi + 1, high, percent_filled);
    }
    return arr;
}

function partition(arr, low, high, percent_filled) {
    var pivot = arr[high];
    var smaller_boundary = low - 1;
    var curr_elem = low;
    for (; curr_elem <= high; curr_elem++) {
        if (arr[curr_elem] < pivot) { // 5
        //if (percent_filled[arr[curr_elem]] < percent_filled[pivot]){
            smaller_boundary++;
            swap(arr, curr_elem, smaller_boundary);
        }
    }
    swap(arr, high, smaller_boundary + 1);
   return smaller_boundary + 1;
}

test_quicksort();
```